# Struts2 Tag library not identified in IntelliJ 12

Tags: intellij-idea, struts2

I have been trying everything to make IntelliJ allow the use of Struts2 taglib. However it keeps on complaining about `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>`.  The error it shows in the IDE is:

> Cannot resolve the uri /struts-tags

[image: Screenshots]

I have set up a new project from scratch and included the struts2 facet (which added the struts.xml file to src/META-INF and the struts2-core jar to myApp/lib).

Is there anything wrong with my project setup ?

Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck with this for a day now!

**Environment: IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seemed to be due to IntelliJ caching and the problem is gone after invalidating cache and restart.

Re-indexing the project did the trick.

```
File > Invalidate Cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not configured a project feature Struts2 properly. You should add File Sets. Right click on the module in the project structure, use Module Config (F4), use Facets, use Struts2 Facet, use File Sets. Press <kbd>+</kbd> button to add configuration files. Make sure `struts.xml` and `struts-default.xml`, and `struts-plugin.xml` are added. The `struts.xml` should not be in `src/META-INF` but in `src` like shown in your picture. But `struts2-core-x.x.x.x.jar` should be on build path. Make sure you have properly configured a project build path, and it should be a valid file containing TLD files inside the jar in the `META-INF` folder.

Comment: Thanks. However, the jars and the filesets are all in order.